# CSS class1 > class2 meaning?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have seen in some code samples class1 > class2 { class definition } . What does the above symbols mean?

Comment: MDN: [Child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Child_selectors).

Answer (score 7):

if `class2` is the direct descendant (child) of `class1`, then apply the rule to elements with class `class2`.

Note that this doesn't work in ie version 7 and lower

A little demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjqzK/

Also please note that it should be written as

`.class1 > .class2` (with dot (`.`) in front of the class name and not just the name)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this demo (please  remove/add (>) then you can see what is the different)

http://jsfiddle.net/pZtTy/1/

Answer (score 1):

class 2 here is the direct child of class 1. for example:

```
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2">
     .....
   </div>
   <div class="class2">
     .....
   </div>
   <div class="class2">
     .....
   </div>
   .....
</div>
```

Then if we call:

```
.class1 > .class2{
    /* something */
}
```

Then only the first "class2" div inside the "class1" div will affect by the style.